# Build JSON-object from form

Tags: javascript, json

I have a form with the following format (only parts of the form)

```
<input type="text" name="Journal[data][serviceaddress][company]" value="{{company}}"/>
<input type="text" name="Journal[data][serviceaddress][address]" value="{{address}}"/>
<input type="text" name="Journal[data][serviceaddress][zip]" value="{{zip}}"/>
<textarea name="Journal[data][serviceaddress][notes]">{{notes}}</textarea>
<input type="text" name="Journal[rows][1][title]"/>
<input type="text" name="Journal[rows][1][body]"/>
<input type="text" name="Journal[rows][2][title]"/>
<input type="text" name="Journal[rows][2][body]"/>
```

I'd like to convert this to the following JSON-object

```
{
    data:{
        serviceaddress:{
            company: "companyvalue",
            address: "addressvalue",
            zip: "zipvalue",
            notes: "notesvalue"
        }
    },
    rows:{
        1:{
            title: "row1title",
            body: "row1body"
        },
        2:{
            title: "row2title",
            body: "row2body"
        }
    }
}
```

Which would be the best way to do this? I thought that i must be someone who did this already, but all i found when searching was people wanting the input name as the key and not nested JSON-data...

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client or server side?

Comment: Assuming you want to do it in JQuery, checkout the serialize API - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/. This might help you.

Comment: jQuery has form.serializeArray() for that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework

Comment: jQuery serializeArray doesn't do nested forms. Gonna look at the other alternatives you suggested. And it is client side.

Comment: `function getSerializedForm(formId) {
     return $(formId).serialize();
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i couldn't find anything existing that i found were a satisfying solution, i created my own and here it is

```
function getData(){
            var data = {};
            $('.data input,.data textarea').each(function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
                var namestr = $(this).attr('name').substr(8);
                namestr = namestr.substring(0,namestr.length-1);
                var namearray = namestr.split('][');

                var currentlevel = data;
                if (namearray[0] == 'data'){
                    namearray = namearray.splice(1,namearray.length);
                    for (var i=0;i < namearray.length;i++){
                        if (currentlevel[namearray[i]] == undefined && i != namearray.length-1){
                            currentlevel[namearray[i]] = {};
                        }
                        else if (namearray.length-1 == i){
                            currentlevel[namearray[i]] = val;
                            break;
                        } //In the end, put a value
                        currentlevel = currentlevel[namearray[i]]
                    }   
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
```

As you can see, this only looks at input/textarea-tags where the first "array" parameter in the name is "data", that is it will only parse fields where name is of the format "Myform[data][value1]". This can easily be modified to your own needs.