# How to correctly create 'charge' in Stripe nodejs library?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

## Client

I'm using Stripe Checkout custom integration - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom - in a following way:

```
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'YOUR_KEY_HERE',
    image: 'images/logo-48px.png',
    token: function(token, args) {
        $.post("http://localhost:3000/charge", {token: token}, function(res) {
            console.log("response from charge: " + res);
        })
    }
  })
```

Using **custom** contrary to **simple** - [How can I modify Stripe Checkout to instead send an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352630/how-can-i-modify-stripe-checkout-to-instead-send-an-ajax-request#comment33864262_21869885) - because **simple** does not allow me to make an AJAX call.

## Server

https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

> You've got the token for your user's credit card details, now what? Now you charge them money.

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));
    var stripeToken = req.body.token;

    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 0005, // amount in cents, again
        currency: "usd",
        card: stripeToken,
        description: "payinguser@example.com"
    }, function(err, charge) {
        if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
        res.send("completed payment!")
    });
});
```

## Here is the error:

[image]

Is seems to me like I have **last4**, **exp_month**, **exp_year** but for some reason I don't have **number**. Any suggestions / hints / ideas?

Googling for `"The card object must have a value for 'number'"` - 12 results, not much help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "token" you have to give as the `card` argument should actually just be the token id (e.g.: "tok_425dVa2eZvKYlo2CLCK8DNwq"), not the full object. Using Checkout your app never sees the card number.

You therefeore need to change:

```
var stripeToken = req.body.token;
```

to:

```
var stripeToken = req.body.token.id;
```

The documentation isn't very clear about this `card` option, but the [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge) has an example.

Comment: It should also be noted that ```The minimum amount is £0.50``` (I was charging too little)

Comment: I can't believe how unclear this is in the docs. Just cost me about an hour!

Answer (score 0):

After `npm install stripe` do this

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_yourstripeserversecretkey");
var chargeObject = {};
chargeObject.amount = grandTotal * 100;
chargeObject.currency = "usd";
chargeObject.source = token-from-client;
chargeObject.description = "Charge for joe@blow.com";

stripe.charges.create(chargeObject)
.then((charge) => {
    // New charge created. record charge object
}).catch((err) => {
    // charge failed. Alert user that charge failed somehow

        switch (err.type) {
          case 'StripeCardError':
            // A declined card error
            err.message; // => e.g. "Your card's expiration year is invalid."
            break;
          case 'StripeInvalidRequestError':
            // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            break;
          case 'StripeAPIError':
            // An error occurred internally with Stripe's API
            break;
          case 'StripeConnectionError':
            // Some kind of error occurred during the HTTPS communication
            break;
          case 'StripeAuthenticationError':
            // You probably used an incorrect API key
            break;
          case 'StripeRateLimitError':
            // Too many requests hit the API too quickly
            break;
        }
});
```

Comment: can this be written like this:  var charge = await stripe.charges.create(chargeObject); ? (with a try catch to handle the error?)