# How to get selected checkbox name in javascript without a button action

Tags: javascript

I have to get all the selected checkboxes value in a JavaScript without any button action in the form and display in my jsp page.

This is my code where I am getting the value from database.

```
<span><li class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" value="${subFill.fillingname}"  name="fillings"> ${subFill.fillingname}</input>
</li></span>
```

I have to select multiple checkbox and get those name.

Comment: Show that code that you've tried so far....

Comment: possible duplicate of [form serialize javascript (no framework)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `namesArray` will hold the `value`s off all the checkboxes which were checked.

You can loop through this array and display the values on JSP page.
Sorry, I'm not much exprienced with JSP but guess that is possible. The js code is,

```
var namesArray = [];
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(this.checked){
            console.log(this.value);
namesArray.push(this.value);
console.log(namesArray);
                }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:- For addition of values to a div and saving the values in session**

To add the values to a div use,

```
  var namesArray = [];
    var div = document.getElementById('divID'); //mention your div's id
        var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            checkBoxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
                if(this.checked){
                    console.log(this.value);
                    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + this.value + ' ';
                    namesArray.push(this.value);
                    console.log(namesArray);
                        }
            });
        }
```

Then to send these values to the server, use ajax on form submit, send the `namesArray` as the `data`. 
Have a look at these, [example1](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/ajax-with-servlets-using-jquery-and-json.html), [example2](http://binodsuman.blogspot.in/2009/05/get-start-with-ajax-ajax-siimple.html), [example3](http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/) etc.
To save these values in a session, write some logic in the servlet. Store a `key-value` pair in the `Session`, key being a `String` or something, and value being an Array of Strings, i.e., in this case the values of checkboxes. So you can get the array by doing `Session.get('your key')`. Hope this helps.

Comment: sir tell me how can i use that script variable in my jsp page and in my session

Comment: How do you want to show these values? I mean in a list or div? Whre should these values be added?

Comment: In a div...........can I able to maintain this variable in a session to get this on next page

Comment: have edited. Hope it helps your cause.