# FormData.get function is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, form-data

FormData.get is undefined in Chrome

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: no, there's no typo, I output the formData itself and console show's the prototype and available functions

Comment: [Just scroll down a little bit in your link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Chrome does not support the `.get()` method, as well as `delete`, `get`, `getAll`, `has`, and `set`. Although you can enable that functionality by activating an experimental flag, [note from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

> [2] Chrome support for methods other than append is currently behind the "Enable Experimental Web Platform Features" flag.

For activating flags in Chrome you can go to the following link:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-webkit-features
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is this: FormData appeared long ago, but not everyone has updated the software ... so Chrome 49.0 pops up somewhere ... or some mobile browsers.

Solution: use other methods of collecting and submitting the form like jquery or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661219/12972080.