# How to use ajax add to cart for related products magento

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I'm trying to use ajax add to the cart in related products but I don't know how to get link to the each related products?

I would like to use ajax and not be redirected to the cart page when I click add to the cart. For the main product this is working well. But for related is adding the main product or adding related product but redirect me to the cart.

```
 <?php endif; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
                </a>

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Can I use

```
productAddToCartForm.submit(this)
```

But what to pass inside submit?

This is the **add to cart code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                if (!url) {
                    url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
                }
                url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajaxcart/index"); // New Code
                var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                data += '&isAjax=1';
                jQuery('#loading-mask').show();
                try {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : url,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        type : 'post',
                        data : data,
                        success : function(data) {
                            jQuery('#loading-mask').hide();
                            if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                                alert(data.message);
                            }else{
                                if(jQuery('.top-links .right-links')){
                                    jQuery('.top-links .right-links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                }
                                jQuery('#after-loading-success-message').show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                }                
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your javascript script which makes AJAX request?

Answer (score -1):

You can serialize the data from product form and send it to server via AJAX request (
[via Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/serialize/) | [via jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) | [via plain JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework)).

Comment: Hi thanks for replay, I'm not sure how  to do it, I can get link to the product using
 onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">

Comment: All necessary data you can get from the product form. For example `var productForm = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form'); 
var requestURL = productForm.attr('action'); 
var requestPostData = productForm.serialize();`

Comment: Hi I've updated script add to cart in my question, there's `serialize()` there, should I add variable in script to get this url for related product? Or get the product link via php and use in `productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url)` but how to? how to pass this url? Or Should I use `var requestURL = productForm.attr('action');` and in `productAddToCartForm.submit(requestURL)` ??

Comment: Did you try just use `productAddToCartForm.submit()` (without parameters)?