# Fetch: Can you pass parameters to the server

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm using a basic fetch to obtain data from an express server that queries the data from a database. So I want to do a login system, i want to send the user/password from the input fields with the fetch request. so i can perform the logical check to see if password matches the data in the server. and respond with the result.
Is it possible to do a fetch that can pass parameters?

Updated Code Below:

```
let fetchData = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },

  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.user,
    password: this.state.password
  })
}

var fromServer = fetch('http://localhost:3000/', fetchData)
.then(function(response){
  if( !response.ok){
    throw Error (response.statusText);
  }
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => console.log("there was an error --> " + error));
```

Express function

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var uname = req.body.username;
  var pw = req.body.password;
  console.log(uname);
  console.log(pw);
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Of course you can!

Here is an example of Fetch using a POST request:

```
fetch("http://example.com/api/endpoint/", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },

  //make sure to serialize your JSON body
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: myName,
    password: myPassword
  })
})
.then( (response) => { 
   //do something awesome that makes the world a better place
});
```

I've answered this question before, check this for more details:

[POST Request with Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565706/post-request-with-fetch-api/39565776#39565776)

To process the request in Express, as mentioned in your comment assuming your express server is setup to parse body requests, you can do this:

```
app.post('/your/route', function(req, res) {
    var name= req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // ...do your bidding with this data
});
```

Comment: oh alright, and on the server side, do i just do a app.get? or app.post function?

Comment: Based on my example, and assuming you are working with ExpressJS, then yes app.post() is what you need to process that request.

Comment: ugh i feel like an idiot, i'm getting the post request but im not sure how to extract the data i'm passing over to express. in the app.post() function.

Comment: Parsing your data is a different issue, please follow this tutorial and specially pay attention to the body-parser section needed for JSON post requests: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters

Comment: I've updated my response to show how it would be done, assuming your Express server is configured as the tutorial or similarly.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense, since you placed the info into the body you can try to find it in the request.body. Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Comment: However i'm now getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined Error. Did i do something wrong here?

Comment: Actually i did a console log, after placing the user and pw into the body with fetchData.body.username and got an undefine return. somehow the data is not being put in

Comment: I finally got it fully functional, it was the JSON parsing that was giving me some problems. Thank you so much for your patience and guidance!