# How to send json data in post-request to url in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i want to send data like this

```
{"update_id":121631120,"message":{"message_id":1,"from":{"id":"TGID","is_bot":false,"first_name":"ELBARON @LxEEE","username":"USERNAME","language_code":"en"},"chat":{"id":"TGID","first_name":"ELBARON @LxEEE","username":"USERNAME","type":"private"},"date":1594553383,"text":"TEXT"}}
```

to this url

```
http://hfkm.ga/market/usersbothf/491856302/suc.php
```

using javascript, but i can't find somthing help.

Comment: Use window fetch API. Try this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39565776/8523378

Comment: @imViki Error "This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios can be used to send HTTP requests like the fetch api. For installing axios use: `npm install axios`  (assuming nodejs is installed)

OR

you can use the CDN: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>` (paste this in your index.html)

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/login',
    data: {
        update_id: 121631120,
        message: {
            message_id: 1,
            from: {like so...}
        }
    }
})
.then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

For more details : https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/

Comment: i don't want to use npm   just i need to do what this site do https://reqbin.com/ using js