# Query Uniswap using GraphQL for ETH price

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, uniswap

I am new to Uniswap and GraphQL... I am trying to fetch the price of ETH using *node.js* and have the following call. The body of the response is unfortunately `undefined` for some reason. Could you please let me know what I might be doing wrong here?

```js
const uniSwapResponse = await fetch("https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: '{ bundle(id: "1" ) {ethPrice} }' })
});

console.log(uniSwapResponse.data);
```

**EDIT:**

The below did the trick for me:

```
fetch("https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: '{ bundle(id: "1") {ethPrice} }' })
}).then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => console.log("ETH price:", data.data.bundle.ethPrice))
```

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` in `async` function only.
The simplest approach would be:

```js
fetch("https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: 'ethPrice { bundle(id: "1") {  ethPrice } }' })
})
.then((response) => { console.log(response) });
```

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565706/post-request-with-fetch-api).

Comment: Many thanks for your response Jerry. I had it wrapped in an async function. The issue is more to the with the way I make the request somehow. If you run your code in a node project, you should also get an undefined response. Could you please let me know if you observe a different response on your end?

Comment: Well, I'm using [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwog907n/) and it gives me full response object, with _arrayBuffer_, _blob_, _body_, etc.

Comment: Many thanks Jerry, I edited my question but thanks for directing me to the right path...