# how to save values from a form into variables

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save values from inputs in the form into variables
 Like this example.

```
<form action="test3" method="POST">
      Activity name: <input type="text" name="fname" id='nm'><br>
      input1: <input type="text" name="input1" id='in1'><br>
      input2: <input type="text" name="input2" id='in2'><br>
      output1: <input type="text" name="output1" id='out1'><br>
      output2: <input type="text" name="output2" id='out2'><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    var valname=document.getElementById("nm").value;
    var valin1=document.getElementById("in1").value;
    var valin2=document.getElementById("in2").value;
    var valout1=document.getElementById("out1").value;
    var valout2=document.getElementById("out2").value;
```

Now, how can i get value into a general variable like : var valeur=valin1;

Comment: I assume he means serialising @prasad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [form serialize javascript (no framework)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FormData`

`var form = document.querySelector('form');
var data = new FormData(form);`

Best off adding an ID to the form though and `getById` as if you had multiple forms on a page, this wouldn't solve it.

[Mozilla API Docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Note that FormData have no support under ie10

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thanks @BurakAkyıldız I thought I added it.