# Using JavaScript to submit form data with HTTP request same like ajax form serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In jQuery, we have `$('form').serialize()` to post all the form data in a single line. Is there any method available in JavaScript to post form data like this or is there an alternative in JavaScript for the code below code?

```
var url = "path.php"; 
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#idForm").serialize(), //like this i need in js
       success: function(data)
       {
       }
});
```

Comment: jQuery is built with JavaScript, you could look at the source code for `.serialize()` and `$.ajax()` to see what it's doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [form serialize javascript (no framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FormData, like this:

```
let data = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
```

And then:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "url");
request.send(data);
```

More info: [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Serialize is creating a parameter string like
field1=value1&field2=value2

When using the jquery ajax, the data can provided as object or array

```
var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
var formData = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    formData[x.elements[i].name] = x.elements[i].value;
}

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: formData
       success: function(data)
       {
       }
});
```