# Serialize form data to json react

Tags: javascript, json, forms, reactjs, events

How I can serialize data in react ?

```
<form method="post" action="/insert" onSubmit={(e)=>this.addMysql(e)}>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="nameUser"/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="passs"/>
    <button type="submit" type="submit">Dodaj</button>
</form>
```

This is my function

```
addMysql(event){
    console.log(event.targe) //this outputs an empty form
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I dont want use State. Just onSubmit send all form data to AddMysql

https://medium.com/@snirlugassy/generic-input-handler-with-react-js-44a97e22cd0d

Thanks  Sag1v

Comment: "_I dont want use State_" - Why use react then?

Comment: Do you know how i can make this 
    `setStateVal(e){
        this.setState({
            e.target.name:e.target.value
        })
    }` I dont want do function for each input to change state I want do it byt one function to each input

Comment: something like [this](https://medium.com/@snirlugassy/generic-input-handler-with-react-js-44a97e22cd0d)?

Comment: Sag1v this work thx

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `states` because that is the *Reacty* way. if not, I may suggest a few things.

Normally I would have suggested to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API, but it is not supported by ***IE*** and older browsers.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30153391/5268235) should get you going, because its a plain JS version of `serialize`.

Finnally [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) if you're using **jQuery**, which I think you're not or you're not supposed to.

Answer (score -1):

```js
//So, here's a simple trick i use to get this done:
//Using React Hook

    

const [data, setData] = useState({});
//the create an onInputChange function for the Inputs this way
const onInputChange = async e =>{
  const {name, value} = e.target;
  //check to validate if entry is not a number
  if(isNaN(name)){
    data[name] = value;
    
    //somehow update data
    setData({...data})
  }
}
```