# window.URLSearchParams broken on Edge

Tags: javascript

I'm trying something like the following;

```
let formUrl = new window.URLSearchParams(
        new window.FormData(this.searchForm)
      ).toString()
```

But I'm getting '0: Invalid argument'

This works on every browser apart from edge.

Has anyone run into this issue before

Comment: Which Edge version are you trying? Did you try to print each of the parts of your statement to see if something is undefined in Edge?

Answer (score 6):

The problem in Edge is that [they do not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility) destructuring of FormData object. (`for ... of` in linked table).

Indeed, you are relying on this behavior from other browsers in your code, because `URLSearchParams( init )` constructor accepts a [*record*](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-record) as `init` parameter.

[The specs](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-urlsearchparams-new) read

> 3. Otherwise, if init is a record, then for each *name* → *value* in init, append a new name-value pair whose name is *name* and value is *value*, to query’s list.

So this means that your code is actually doing

```js
const formData = new FormData( searchForm );

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
for ( let [ name, value ] of formData ) {
  urlParams.append( name, value );
}
let formUrl = urlParams.toString();

console.log( formUrl );
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">
  <input name="foo" value="bar">
  <input name="baz" value="bla">
</form>
```

But since, once again, Edge doesn't support destructuring of FormData, your code breaks.

However, according to MDN, they do support `for ... of FormData.entries()`, so maybe this would work (no Edge to test though so let me know).

```js
let formUrl = new window.URLSearchParams(
  new window.FormData(this.searchForm)
    .entries() // explicitely call .entries() to get the iterator
).toString()

console.log( formUrl );
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">
  <input name="foo" value="bar">
  <input name="baz" value="bla">
</form>
```

Comment: I had to spread the entries into an array to actually get them working in Edge. `new URLSearchParams([...(new FormData(this.searchForm)).entries()])`

Answer (score 2):

A nice answer to another question that gives you the right code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033425/1568714

Basically, do this

```
new URLSearchParams(Array.from(new FormData(formElement))).toString()
```

Kaiido's answer explains the problem well, but using that approach you will get issues in iOS safari versions < 10.3 and chrome versions < 53, where `.entries` is not supported. (https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-entries)