# How to get the values of all the fields of a form onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a form which is implemented using `react-bootstrap`. I populate the default values of the fields when the form is mounted.(Default values are taken using a API). I want to make the submit button disabled if no change is done for the form. My approach is to compare the initial values of the form with the updated values `onChange` form. But i cannot get the values of all the fields in the form using `onChange`. I can only get the values `onSubmit` but it does not help what i'm trying to achieve.

So when i receive the props i'm setting the data to an object like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const { login } = this.props;
    console.log("Joker ", login.userInformation);

    const data = {
    "name"    : login.userInformation && login.userInformation.name,
    "address" : {
                    "address"   : login.userInformation && login.userInformation.address.address,
                    "cep"       : login.userInformation && login.userInformation.address.cep,
                    "city"      : login.userInformation && login.userInformation.address.city,
                    "country"   : login.userInformation && login.userInformation.address.country
                }
    }
    this.setState({
        initialData: data
    })
}
```

Ideally I want to achieve something like this for `onChange`

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    const { updateUserInfo, userPictureUpload, login } = this.props;
    const userInfoAddress = login.userInformation !== null ? login.userInformation.address : '';
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    event.preventDefault();

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

    } else {

        const profileData = {
            "name"    : event.target.formUserName.value,
            "address" :  {
                            "address"   : event.target.formAddress.value,
                            "cep"       : event.target.formPostalCode.value,
                            "city"      : event.target.formCity.value,
                            "country"   : this.state.country === '' ? userInfoAddress.country : this.state.country
                         }
        }

        var eq = JSON.stringify(this.state.initialData) === JSON.stringify(profileData);
        if (!eq) {
            updateUserInfo(profileData);
        } else {
            alert("same");
        }        
    }
};
```

But I cannot get the values for fields using onChange like `event.target.formAddress.value` . How can I get the data of field `onChange` of a form?

Comment: You have `const form = event.currentTarget;` - use that - change all event.target. to form

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033425/295783

Comment: @mplungjan how can i use event.currentTarget to catch the field data?

Comment: I assume the actual rendered form has `<input name="formAddress"/>` No?

Comment: Alternatively run over form.elements