# Why does req.body return null when I was use event.preventDefault() with fetch api, express, and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, fetch

I want to submit a form and then return an object from my MongoDB database without reloading the page. Therefore when I submit my form I use an event handler that prevents the default behavior of the form to reload the page. The problem is this is interfering with my server side script and causing `req.body` to return null. If I remove `e.preventDefault()` from my client side script then `req.body` works fine but the page refreshes and just displays a json from my database. How would I get around this?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <title>Message in a Bottle</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "icon">
            <img id = "iconImg" style = "width:100%"src = "icon.svg"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "form">
            <form method="post" action="/">
                <input type="text" name="sender"/>
                <textarea rows="20" cols="50" name="message"></textarea>
                <button type = "submit" onclick="onClick(event)">submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = "message">
            <p id = "senderName"></p>
            <p id = "response"></p>
            <button onclick="closeMessage()">New Message</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "packageHandler.js"></script>

</html>
```

Here is my client side script:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const icon = document.getElementById("icon");
const message = document.getElementById("message");


function onClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("loading results");
    form.style.opacity = "0%";
    form.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    icon.style.width = "80%";
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {method: 'POST'})
        .then((response) => {
        icon.style.width = "33%";
        message.style.opacity = "100%";
        message.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        return response.json();
    })
        .then((data) => {
        document.getElementById("senderName").innerHTML = data.name;
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data.message;
    });
    //await results
    //fade in <div id = "message">
    //display results in <div id = "message">
}
function closeMessage(){
    console.log("message closed")
    form.style.opacity = "100%";
    form.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    message.style.opacity = "0%";
    message.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    //fade out <div id = "message">
    //fade in <div id = "form"
}
```

Here is my server side script:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
require('dotenv/config');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));

//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('./views/home.html', function (err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const dbo = db.db("mydb");
    const messageTable = dbo.collection("messages");
    let myobj = 
    [{ 
      name: req.body.sender,
      message: req.body.message
    }];
    console.log(myobj)
    messageTable.insertMany(myobj, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document inserted");
    });
    var myPromise = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        messageTable.aggregate(
          [{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]
        ).toArray((err, data) => {
          err
            ? reject(err)
            : resolve(data[0]);
        });
      });
    }
    //Step 2: async promise handler
    var callMyPromise = async () => {
      var result = await (myPromise());
      //anything here is executed after result is resolved
      return result;
    };

    //Step 3: make the call
    callMyPromise().then(function (result) {
      db.close();
      res.json(result)
      });

    });


  });  //end mongo client
```

Comment: Your `fetch` call is missing a request `body`

Comment: @Phil Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Phil be kind and read. It's working when he doesn't use `event.preventDefault()` so maybe there is some predefined behavior of the browser that add the formData to the body it self.

Comment: @PavelB. it works without `preventDefault()` because the form submits normally

Comment: From the linked duplicate, ignore the accepted answer and make sure to read the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a request with `fetch` the data from your form is not included.

To include the data your must manually gather the data and send it with the request.

Super lazy example:

**EDIT**: changed to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) based of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26501400/8781351)

**EDIT 2**: FormData sends as `multipart/form-data` so we need to url-encode it first. (Thanks @Phil)

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

  forms.forEach((form) => form.onsubmit = onsubmit);

function onsubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = e.target;
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  var encodedData = new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()
  // log form values
  console.log(encodedData);
  
  fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: encodedData
  })
  .then(result => {
  
  });
  
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="sender"/>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" name="message"></textarea>
    <button type = "submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OP would need to add `app.use(express.json())` for this to work. Also, you mention the `Content-type` header but you have not added any headers to the request

Comment: Fun fact about submitting a `FormData` instance via `fetch`; this will post a `multipart/form-data` request body

Comment: And the second fun fact. FormData class is great for sending an image or file.

Comment: Another (actually) fun fact, if you set the request body to an instance of `URLSearchParams` (instead of a string), the content-type will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you can omit the `headers` part (also, it's [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/headers), not `header`)

Comment: Finally, I wouldn't recommend using the `onsubmit` property. It's usually better to add event listeners

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the wrong event.

Try using onsubmit event on the form and instead of using `event.preventDefault()`, return false in the onSubmit function.

It will look like something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="onSubmit()">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Then the code:

```
function onSubmit() {
  ... do your thing ...
  return false;
}
```

It should work, but If doesn't, then You will have to add formData to the body yourself. (I will tell you how if needed).

**Update**

1. Add id to the form (you don't have to, but it makes things easier.

   ```html
   <form id="myForm">
     <button></button>
   </form>
   ```
2. get the form data:

   ```js
   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'))
   ```
3. Pass them to the fetch as the request body.

   ```js
   fetch('url', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     },
     body: formData
   })
   ```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now it reloads again.

Comment: @TDonnally ok, then you have to do it the hard way. Give me a sec

Comment: OP doesn't have a JSON request body parser so you shouldn't be posting JSON. Also, you cannot `JSON.stringify()` a `FormData` instance

Comment: Also, if you're using the `onsubmit` attribute, you need to use `onsubmit="return onSubmit()"` for the event default to be prevented

Comment: @Phil thanks, I don't use onsubmit normally. I'm using click event like every other dummy and I don't even use form tag most of the time.

Comment: I'd say it's much better to use `document.querySelector('#form form').addEventListener('submit', ...)`